# Making a list of UIViews that slide up and down when touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to figure out an approach to build something like the image below, which is a list of items that when a section is clicked slides out content. It's a really common UX on most websites and what not. My idea is to have each gray box (button) slide out a UIView containing some other items. I'm still new to iOS development but I'm struggling to find how you can animate a UIView to slide down and push the content below it down as well. Hoping some one can give me a good starting point or point to some info outside the realm of the apple docs.

Thanks!

[image: UIView list layout example]

Comment: you could use a `UITableView` for this. Your cells need to have an expanded state and you could set the height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` when a cell is selected, return a bigger value for it and call `reloadData` to perform the table update

Comment: I see, so you're basically saying to have a total of three cells with adjustable heights in order to show more content rather than having six cells and doing a show/hide type type of action on the content sections?

Comment: I think what @robert is referring to is something like what I describe here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_dynamic_table_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you just have a few views, I would not recommend the `UITableView` approach, since it is not so easy to customize with animations and table views usually want to fill the whole screen with cells. Instead write a expandable `UIView` subclass that has the desired two states. Add a method to switch between extended and collapsed state. On expanding/collapsing adjust their positions so that they always have enough space.

I provide you an example of views adjusting their frames. I guess it should be easy to do the same with auto layout constraints: give the views a fixed height constraint and change this on collapsing/expanding. The same way set the constraints between the views to be 0 so that they are stacked on top of each other.

Expandable View:

```
@interface ExpandingView(){
    UIView *_expandedView;
    UIView *_seperatorView;

    BOOL _expanded;
}
@end

@implementation ExpandingView

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 290, 50)];
    if (self) {
        _expanded = NO;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;

        _headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1];
        [self addSubview:_headerView];

        _seperatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height-1, self.bounds.size.width, 1)];
        _seperatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [self addSubview:_seperatorView];

        _expandedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.bounds, 0, self.bounds.size.height)];
        _expandedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self addSubview:_expandedView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [self adjustLayout];
}

- (void)adjustLayout{
    _headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 50);
    _seperatorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 49, self.bounds.size.width, 1);
    _expandedView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height-50);
}

- (void)toggleExpandedState{
    _expanded = !_expanded;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, _expanded?200:50);
    [self adjustLayout];
}

@end
```

ViewController:

```
@interface ExpandingViewController (){
    NSArray *_expandingViews;
}
@end

@implementation ExpandingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _expandingViews = @[
                    [[ExpandingView alloc] init],
                    [[ExpandingView alloc] init],
                    [[ExpandingView alloc] init],
                    ];

    for(ExpandingView *view in _expandingViews){
        [view.headerView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandingViewTapped:)]];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    int y = 100;
    for(ExpandingView *view in _expandingViews){
        view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.bounds, (CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)-CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds))/2, y);
        y+=view.frame.size.height;
    }
}

- (void)expandingViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapper{
    ExpandingView *view = (ExpandingView*)tapper.view.superview;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.8 initialSpringVelocity:0 options:0 animations:^{
        [view toggleExpandedState];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to give this a try. One question though I notice you reference a _headerView, is that supposed to referenced as an iVar as well?

Comment: I declared that one as property in the .h, so it was easier to add the UITapGestureRecognizer only to the header (the gray part in your image)

Comment: using your method must all the expandable views be built out programmatically or would I be able to build them in interface builder and make them properties of the view controller?

Comment: Of course you can build them using interface builder. It shouldn't make a difference.